# I am having trouble with my code reading this csv file and naming the first column "team"

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am unable to read my csv file into my code correctly for some reason.

[Here is my csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcbsZ.png)

Here is my code:

```
df_playoffs = pd.read_csv('/Users/hannahbeegle/Desktop/playoff_teams.csv', encoding='latin-1', index_col = 'team')
df_playoffs.fillna('None', inplace=True)
```

Here is the error message:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 6692
    sort=sort)

FutureWarning: Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned. A future version
of pandas will change to not sort by default.

To accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=False'.

To retain the current behavior and silence the warning, pass 'sort=True'.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hannahbeegle/Desktop/Baseball.py", line 131, in <module>
    index_col = 'team')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 702, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 435, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1139, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 2069, in read
    index, names = self._make_index(data, alldata, names)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1541, in _make_index
    index = self._get_simple_index(alldata, columns)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1574, in _get_simple_index
    i = ix(idx)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1569, in ix
    raise ValueError('Index %s invalid' % col)
ValueError: Index team invalid
```

Comment: Can you please include the first few lines of the CSV as part of your question?

Comment: @McGlothlin Here is the first few lines:                                                               ARI 1999, 2001, 2002, 2007, 2011, 2017
ATL 1982, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2010, 2012*, 2013, 2018
BAL 1970, 1971, 1973, 1974, 1979, 1983, 1996, 1997, 2012, 2014, 2016*
BOS 1975, 1986, 1988, 1990, 1995, 1998, 1999, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2013, 2016, 2017, 2018
CHC 1984, 1989, 1998, 2003, 2007, 2008, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018
CWS 1983, 1993, 2000, 2005, 2008

Comment: every time there is a new team name, that signifies a new line in the file

Comment: Instead of adding as a comment, please add it to your question with formatting. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: @McGlothlin Done.

Comment: I don't see `team` anywhere in that file.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues I'm seeing here:

**The Warning**

Your warning is due to the way the Python library will be changing its behavior in a future release. This is an attempt at making the code you write today work in the future without an unexpected change in output.

In the past, the parameter `sort` had a default value of `True`. That's why the warning is telling you to set `sort=True` if you want to keep the library's current, default behavior. If you don't want the dataframe sorted, (as it will be the default in the future, do the opposite: `sort=False`.

For this use case, I don't think the choice is going to make any difference to you.

```
df_playoffs = pd.read_csv('/Users/hannahbeegle/Desktop/playoff_teams.csv', encoding='latin-1', index_col = 'Team', sort = False)
df_playoffs.fillna('None', inplace=True)
```

**The Error**

The last line of your error is:

> ValueError: Index team invalid

Looking at your CSV, you don't have a `team` column. You cannot declare an index on a column that doesn't exist. You need to create a new column that contains the team names, or use one that already exists.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your issue and changed my CSV column name from 'team' to 'Team' to correct the problem. Simple spelling mistake from developer end. The error shows panda trying to read from column header that doesn't exist.

You can change your index_col String parameter in:

```
df_playoffs = pd.read_csv('/Users/hannahbeegle/Desktop/playoff_teams.csv', encoding='latin-1', index_col = 'team')
```

to

```
df_playoffs = pd.read_csv('/Users/hannahbeegle/Desktop/playoff_teams.csv', encoding='latin-1', index_col = 'Team')
```

Tested and worked with this code:

```
import pandas as pd 

df_playoffs = pd.read_csv('/Users/hannahbeegle/Desktop/playoff_teams.csv', encoding='latin-1', index_col = 'Team')
df_playoffs.fillna('None', inplace=True)

print(data.head())
```

playoff_teams.csv -- sample

```
Team                                                                         
Dummy data0       None       None       None       None       None       None
Dummy data1       None       None       None       None       None       None
Dummy data2       None       None       None       None       None       None
Dummy data3       None       None       None       None       None       None
Dummy data4       None       None       None       None       None       None
```

Comment: I received the same error when I changed it to your code

Comment: Hi @Hannah, seems like you need to manually input 'team' into the first column header of your CSV file. I looked at the file CSV file you attached and saw 'team' column name is missing.